# jQuery popup does not work - simple custom popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have a simple jquery popup. I am having issues making it work. Right now the popup does not show up. The Live webpage can be seen at: http://www.domainandseo.com/fibro/index.html

If you scroll down a little there is a link that says "click to enlarge" which should make the popup show up.

My html is:

```
<div id="lightbox">
            <a href="" class="cross close"><img src="img/cross.png" alt="X" /></a>
            <img src="img/lightbox-img.jpg" alt="Supplemental Facts" class="lightbox-img" />
        </div>

    <div class="overlay"></div>
```

The CSS is:

```
#lightbox {
    width: 722px;
    height: 732px;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 100px;
    display: none;
}
    .cross {
        float: right;
    }
    .lightbox-img {
        margin-left: 90px;
        margin-top: 45px;
    }

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    height:130%;
    z-index:998;
    background: url(../img/gray.png) repeat;
    display: none;
}
```

And the jQuery for the popup:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//open popup
$(".pop").click(function(){
  $("#lightbox").fadeIn(1000);
  $(".overlay").css ({display: 'block'});
  positionPopup();

});


//close popup
$(".close").click(function(){
    $("#lightbox").fadeOut(500);
    $(".overlay").css ({display: 'none'});
});
});

//position the popup at the center of the page
function positionPopup(){
  if(!$("#lightbox").is(':visible')){
    return;
  } 
  $("#lightbox").css({


  });
}


//maintain the popup at center of the page when browser resized
$(window).bind('resize',positionPopup);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified version that should be easily implemented into your code. The problem with using an anchor tag to trigger the event is that an empty anchor tag will send the user back to the top of the page. Use a `div` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/tvb4X/

Comment: thanks man.. so i guess setting my anchor name to the popup div would be a good solution

Comment: either that or removing the anchor entirely, changing it to a paragraph element or even a div button that activates the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$(".#lightbox")
```

to

```
$("#lightbox")
```

Comment: You link is being followed, maybe you need a return false (or similar)